# Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I got

**Unhandled Runtime Error**

**Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.**

In my NEXT.js (tailwind CSS) App

Please help me to solve this problem.

```
import React from "react";
import { SocialIcon } from "react-social-icons";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import Link from "next/link";

function Header() {
  return (
    <>
      <header className="sticky top-0 p-5 flex items-start justify-between max-w-7xl mx-auto z-20 xl:items-center">
        <motion.div
          initial={{
            x: -500,
            opacity: 0,
            scale: 0.5,
          }}
          animate={{
            x: 0,
            opacity: 1,
            scale: 1,
          }}
          transition={{
            duration: 1.5,
          }}
          className="flex flex-row items-center"
        >
          {/* Social Icons */}
          <SocialIcon
            url="https://twitter.com/"
            fgColor="gray"
            bgColor="transparent"
          />
          <SocialIcon
            url="https://twitter.com/"
            fgColor="gray"
            bgColor="transparent"
          />
          <SocialIcon
            url="https://twitter.com/"
            fgColor="gray"
            bgColor="transparent"
          />
          <SocialIcon
            url="https://twitter.com/"
            fgColor="gray"
            bgColor="transparent"
          />
          <SocialIcon
            url="https://twitter.com/"
            fgColor="gray"
            bgColor="transparent"
          />
          <SocialIcon
            url="https://twitter.com/"
            fgColor="gray"
            bgColor="transparent"
          />
        </motion.div>

        <Link href="#contact">
          <motion.div
            initial={{
              x: 500,
              opacity: 0,
              scale: 0.5,
            }}
            animate={{
              x: 0,
              opacity: 1,
              scale: 1,
            }}
            transition={{
              duration: 1.5,
            }}
            className="flex flex-row items-center text-gray-300 cursor-pointer"
          >
            <div>
              <SocialIcon
                className="cursor-pointer"
                network="email"
                fgColor="gray"
                bgColor="transparent"
              />
              <p className="uppercase hidden md:inline-flex text-sm text-gray-400 ">
                Get In Touch
              </p>
            </div>
          </motion.div>
        </Link>
      </header>
    </>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

**Thi is my code file and this error happen with**

```
              <SocialIcon
                className="cursor-pointer"
                network="email"
                fgColor="gray"
                bgColor="transparent"
              />
```

This part only.
If I removed this icon it won't happen plase help me to solve.

This error happen for firefox and chrome browser also.

Comment: What version of Next.js are you using? Also, what HTML element does `SocialIcon` render?

Comment: import { SocialIcon } from "react-social-icons";

Comment: "next": "13.0.0",

Comment: Ok, but what HTML element does `SocialIcon` render? For example, is it an `a` tag or `button`? `Link` component renders an `a` element and Next.js gets mad if you wrap an `a` with another `a` or a `button` with an `a`, causing this error. That might be the issue.

Comment: Have you included the full error? It will usually tell you exactly what was mismatched, along with the initial and changed values.

Comment: yes  **Unhandled Runtime Error**

Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error

Comment: ivanatias I think it is an a tag, Because it open the email box, How can solve this problem

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue.

instead of this:

```
<Link href="#contact">
      <motion.div
        initial={{
          x: 500,
          opacity: 0,
          scale: 0.5,
        }}
        animate={{
          x: 0,
          opacity: 1,
          scale: 1,
        }}
        transition={{
          duration: 1.5,
        }}
        className="flex flex-row items-center text-gray-300 cursor-pointer"
      >
        <div>
          <SocialIcon
            className="cursor-pointer"
            network="email"
            fgColor="gray"
            bgColor="transparent"
          />
          <p className="uppercase hidden md:inline-flex text-sm text-gray-400 ">
            Get In Touch
          </p>
        </div>
      </motion.div>
    </Link>
```

Do this:

```
<motion.div
    initial={{
      x: 500,
      opacity: 0,
      scale: 0.5,
    }}
    animate={{
      x: 0,
      opacity: 1,
      scale: 1,
    }}
    transition={{
      duration: 1.5,
    }}
    className="flex flex-row items-center text-gray-300 cursor-pointer"
  >
    <SocialIcon
      className="cursor-pointer"
      network="email"
      url="#contact"
      fgColor="gray"
      bgColor="transparent"
    />

    <Link href="#contact">
      <p className="uppercase hidden md:inline-flex text-sm text-gray-400">
        get in touch
      </p>
    </Link>
  </motion.div>
```

This will resolve the issue. It was happening because Link is also an  tag and SocialIcon is also an  tag. so, this was leading to  inside of .

Answer (score 1):

If you look inside your console, you will find the following error:

`Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <a> cannot appear as a descendant of <a>.`

This is the `<SocialIcon>` inside of the `<Link>` tag - aka `<a>` inside `<a>`.
My solution to your same problem was to wrap the `<p>`tag with the `<Link>` tag rather than the entire `<motion.div>`.